# Unmanaged application receiving callback from a c# delegate

Tags: c#, c++, delegates, action

I am creating C# dll using class library solution. Class contain few parameters like :
1. Public functions
2. Public variable
3. Public delegate
etc....

I have a native, unmanaged C++ application, which uses a C# library by wrapping it with a C++/CLI class wrapper (using : https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/creating-a-com-server-using-c/)

The C# library raises some events, which I can capture in C# code and handle them.

I want to send those events to an unmanaged C++ class, as a callback. Which would be the way to go for this?

Comment: Can the C# get the event and call appropriate code? Or are you asking if you can wire the callbacks directly to the events on the C++ side?

Comment: yes, I want to ask, is there any way to trigger C++ function from C# delegate?

Comment: As in directly? Why not write some C# wrapping code that calls what you need?